# Problem with downloading multiple url data with wget

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget, url

I have a text file `download.txt`. Here I'm showing only 8 files url. My original file has 900 urls to download.

```
https://www.web.org/download/OE056783
https://www.web.org/download/OE078945
https://www.web.org/download/OE023456
https://www.web.org/download/OE098745
https://www.web.org/download/OE090123
https://www.web.org/download/OE067453
https://www.web.org/download/OE089234
https://www.web.org/download/OE012345
```

I tried downloading data with `wget -i download.txt`. But, I am having a problem.

I see this error:

```
--2020-07-13 16:53:04--  https://www.web.org/download/OED056783
Resolving www.web.org (www.web.org)... 202.127.3.168
Connecting to www.web.org (www.web.org)|202.127.3.168|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200
Length: 2876489216 (2.7G) [application/x-download]
Saving to: ‘OED056783’

 0% [>                                                                                                                                                          ] 19,365,497  6.76KB/s   in 7m 32s

2020-07-13 17:00:39 (41.8 KB/s) - Read error at byte 19365497/2876489216 (Connection reset by peer).
```

1. what could be the issue here?
2. With `wget -i download.txt` I'm able to download each file at a time. Is there a way to download 10/20 files each time, so that downloading 900 files will complete faster.

Comment: Have you considered writing a wrapper script using a for loop?

Comment: Not too clear, you first state "I tried downloading data with `wget -i download.txt`. But, I am having a problem.", and later you say: "With `wget -i download.txt` I'm able to download each file at a time"... Go figure...This said the server could be actively preventing you from hogging bandwidth with parallel downloads.

Comment: @xenoid the second question I asked here is about downloading multiple files in parallel...with the above used command I see its downloading single file at once and even then I see the above error.